# The mysql_fetch_array() is duplicating every thing

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hey guys (and girls) I'm having a problem with arrays, this code below looks like duplicating each column inside a array! :/

```
<?php
//quantidade_de_registro
include("mysqlconfig.inc");
$query = "SELECT * FROM contas ";
$res = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
$arr[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

It will returns something like this:

```
[{"0":"5","ID":"5","1":"Zenny","Login":"Zenny","2":"Zeny","Nome":"Zeny","3":"daniel_queiroz789@hotmail.com","Email":"daniel_queiroz789@hotmail.com","4":"23021994","Senha":"23021994"}]
```

Each Column appears twice, But I need each column appears just once, a friend mine said that I need to re-parse the array and put it into the array, I don't know what it means or how I can do that :/

Please help :)

Comment: The `mysql` methods have been deprecated; you should be using `mysqli` instead. See the [docs](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

No, don't do that.  Instead use `PDO` or `mysqli` and their respective fetch methods.

[`mysql_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) fetches both numeric and associative arrays simultaneously.

Comment: Wow Thx thats worked, What do you recommend me? PDO or mysqli for online game and stuffs?

Comment: @Daniel I personally prefer PDO *much* more

Answer (score 1):

you can modify your script by adding a second parameter to the fetch

```
mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC)
```

However I will second that you should use PDO or mysqli instead

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array() as it's second paramter by default at "MYSQL_BOTH" meaning it return an array with both numerical and associative key.

To have only one of those, you can specify it in the call

```
mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC); // for assosiative
// OR
mysql_fetch_array($resm MYSQL_NUM); // for numeric
```

For more information you can take a look at the PHP documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: for numeric? hmmm.... thats is new thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). The [PDOStatement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) class fetch methods allow you to set the format of the returned data.

Here is some code for retrieving your data in an associative array:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM contas");
    if($sth->execute()) {
        $contacts = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($contacts);
    } else {
          throw new PDOException(print_r($sth->errorInfo(), true));
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```